# Azure IoT Hub Event EndPoint Retention Time Not Working?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I set the event retention time to 1 day (the lowest value and think it's default) in my Azure IoT Hub.

I can see from usage donut diagram that each day it resets to 0% usage and 0 message.

However, when I start my Stream Analytics with custom start time (say 2 mths ago), why would I still be able to pick up older events/messages?

Anyone notice this behavior too?

Thanks!

Comment: It is the minimal retention time, in reality it is much longer but you just cannot guarantee it will be there longer than the specified retention.

Comment: OK - thanks!  The UI makes it looks like that after a day, the IoT Hub will be clear/empty which what I was expected.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2015/03/09/data-retention-in-event-hubs/
Here is the explanation.